# What are the main results of sheaf theory?

Tags: soft-question, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, motivation

I am learning some sheaf theory and sheaf cohomology from the book by Torsten Wedhorn.

Sheaves seem to be quite a flexible tool, since one can have sheaves of rings, sheaves of abelian groups and so on.

My question is: are there some important results in sheaf theory , given how flexible they appear to be as a tool ? or are the results specialised to particular types of sheaves over particular types of topological spaces ?

Comment: Sheaf theory is not really a subject in itself for most people. Sheaves are just tools that are useful and show up naturally in a lot of situations. There are not many people that study sheaves for their own sakes. As such, most interesting things obtained by using sheaves are not about sheaves, but about some other field, in which sheaves happen to be a useful tool.